# Traceur compiler: normalize / resolve

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, traceur

As I understood I can use traceur compiler in two ways:

- compile scripts and then include already compiled into my app
- use `traceur` in browser so all scripts will be transformed in app's runtime

So how can I use normalize and resolve functions? As I know they should be stored under System namespace - `System.normalize = function(){...}` and `System.resolve = function(){...}`

I added them, but they were not called.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function as System.resolve.

See https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/wiki/Overriding-System-Loader-behavior.