# Traceur compiler for production

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, traceur

Is it ready for using in production? Especially for large applications.

As i understand  - yes. But it would be great to get more details.

Also there are two ways to use it:

- runtime
- pre-compilation

How much more time will take runtime execution than pre-compilation? As I tested, it is near x10-15 times but may be somebody has other info?

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not it's ready for production is a subjective issue.  One needs to consider performance, reliability, and bandwidth. It's hard to see performance being an issue since it's just compiling down into ES5. As for reliablity, in all the time I've used traceur I've experienced no bugs whatsoever. Bandwidth-wise, you'll need to download the traceur runtime, but that's not large compared to all the other stuff we're downloading these days. So my own opinion would be **yes**.

With regard to pre-compilation, it's not a question of how many times slower. The compilation itself takes the same amount of time. The question is whether it happens in advance or each time you load the webpage. Although Traceur is remarkably fast, a medium-sized code base could still take several seconds to compile. That is probably not something you want your users to experience. So yes, best practice is **absolutely** to pre-compile for production.

Comment: Thank you for response. I also thought same but I can not understand how can I use `resolve` / `normalize` functions from [Compilation pipeline](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/93558f56d780c95b0ac4f400a33c8a12381aa919/687474703a2f2f636c2e6c792f696d6167652f30643250336a3274326230732f5061737465645f496d6167655f335f31305f31335f355f31365f504d2e706e67). I know how to use them in runtime but I found no info about them in pre-compilation. And same with `System.paths` or `System.map`.

Comment: Also I posted separated questions at SO: - [Paths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26665310/traceur-compiler-paths) and [Normalize / Resolve](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26665210/traceur-compiler-normalize-resolve)

Comment: I don't know about those things but why do you think you need them?

Comment: I think yes. I think this is important feature. I could simplify import paths. `import Foo from tracker.resources';` If `System.map['tracker.*] = '/app/modules/tracker/services/*];` etc